# How can I fix the error "Invalid variant 'parent': value 'CustomEntityDataTemplate'" when using ConnectApi.Mentions.getMentionCompletions()?

Tags: apex, chatter

I'm trying to use the code below to retrieve mention completions (suggestions for usernames to @mention) in a Community.

```
   public String getMentionCompletions(String communityId, String searchTerm, String objectId){

        ConnectApi.MentionCompletionPage page = ConnectApi.Mentions.getMentionCompletions(communityId, searchTerm, objectId);

        List<MentionCompletion> mentionCompletions = new List<MentionCompletion>();

        for(ConnectAPI.MentionCompletion completion : page.mentionCompletions){
            MentionCompletion mc = new MentionCompletion(completion.name);
            mentionCompletions.add(mc);
        }

        return JSON.serializePretty(mentionCompletions);

    }

    private class MentionCompletion {

        String uid;
        String value;

        public mentionCompletion(String name){
            uid = name;
            value = name;
        }
    }
```

The code works fine when run as Anonymous Apex, returning the mention suggestions as expected.  However, when run as a user logged in to the community, the line with the call to ConnectApi.Mentions.getMentionCompletions() produces the error:

> Invalid variant 'parent': value 'CustomEntityDataTemplate'

The Community ID and object ID are accessible by the community user, and googling the error message hasn't produced any insights so far.  Any ideas how I can resolve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I work for Salesforce and haven't been able to repro the problem. Unless someone else here can figure it out, can you please contact Salesforce Support and have a case entered so that I can work with a support rep to investigate it more deeply?

Comment: Just opened a case - cheers alouie.